# Creating multiple timestamps on Google Sheets to make dependent drop-down boxes work

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp, google-apps-script-triggers

I need timestamps on two different sheets to make two different dependent drop boxes work. I use the scripts below but can only get one sheet to work and not both sheets:

#### Script time in

```
function onEdit(event) {

  //SETTINGS
  var tsheet = 'In';
  var lcol = 2;
  var rcol = 8;
  var tcol = 9;
  //

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  if (sname == 'In') {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    if (scol>= lcol<=rcol) {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

#### Script Time out

```
function onEdit(event) {

  //SETTINGS
  var tsheet = 'Out';
  var lcol = 2;
  var rcol = 8;
  var tcol = 9;
  //

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sname = s.getName();
  if (sname == 'Out') {
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var scol = r.getColumn();
    if (scol>= lcol<=rcol) {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Common practice is to marked the answer as best answered. Read our [help] or take the [tour] to know more about that. Welcome to Web Applications !!

Answer (score 2):

Having two onEdit scripts isn't gonna work. So try to merge the two scripts into one...

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    sheets = ['In', 'Out'],
    ind = sheets.indexOf(s.getName());
    if (ind === -1 || e.range.columnStart < 2 || e.range.columnStart > 8) return;
e.range.offset(0, 9 - e.range.columnStart)
    .setValue(new Date())
}
```

.. and see if that works ?

Comment: JPV, it works brilliantly! Really appreciate your help, after trying to figure it out myself for 2 days:) Thanks Jeroen